Heisenberg's uncertainity principle with Energy and time

I didn't exactly understand the measurement of time in here. In Heisenberg's uncertainity principle involving position and momentum in one direction, uncertainity principle states that we cannot measure them accurately simulatmeously, in here both the properties are of the particle and mesuring one collapses wave function, but time between measuring energies is not a property of particle right? I can find the time between measurements using an external clock. so why does it matter in heisenberg's principle. If the particle is in energy eigenstate then shouldn't it always give the same energy if we measure it, irrespective of time between measurement.

This question is similar to: What is $\Delta t$ in the time-energy uncertainty principle?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

"Complementary" in this context refers to observables, and time is not a quantum mechanical observable, so the first sentence of your second paragraph is meaningless, as is all that follows from it.
